# How do I create a Tiling layout / Flow layout in TkInter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, flowlayout

I want to to fill my window with, say, labels and I want them to wrap once the column would be bigger than the current window (or rather parent frame) size.

I've tried using the `grid` layout, but then I have to calculate the size of the content of each row myself, to know when to put the next element in the next row.

The reason I ask, is because I want to create some sort of tiled file icons.

Or asked differently, is there something like Swing's `FlowLayout` for TkInter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I do when I want something like this is use the text widget for a container. The text widget can have embedded widgets, and they wrap just like text. As long as your widgets are all the same height the effect is pretty nice.

For example (cut and pasted from the question at the author's request):

```
textwidget = tk.Text(master)
textwidget.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
for f in os.listdir('/tmp'):
    textwidget.window_create(tk.INSERT, window=tk.Label(textwidget, text=f))
```

Comment: Great! thank you. please insert the code example i provided into your answer, so the next person looking for this doesn't have to look up the docs on the text widget :)

Comment: The user can still use the `Text` as a text box, and type text or delete items with backspace etc, which is most likely undesirable for using it as a GUI manager. You can disable editing with `textwidget.config(state=tk.DISABLED)`. Even so, the user can select text/empty space, and the cursor looks like a text cursor. Those two things can finally also be fixed with the following code which sets the background selection color to the regular background color of the text box, and changes the cursor into an arrow.  `textwidget.config(selectbackground=textwidget.cget('background'), cursor='arrow')`

Comment: @nitro2k01: an arguably simpler solution is to simply add key bindings that disable selection. Also, when the widget is disabled there will be no insertion cursor, so changing it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

##### Here is a way to make flow behavior inside a frame.

I wrote a function that will do this.  Basically you pass a frame to the function (not root or top level) and the function will look at all the children of the frame, go through them measure their sizes and place them in the frame.

###### Here is the placement procedure

- Place the first widget, and move x over an amount equal to its width.
- Measure the next widget.
- If placing the next widget would cause it to goes past the frame width, bump its x value to 0 and bump it down a y value equal to the largest widget in the current row (start a new row).
- Reset the value of the largest widget since you are starting a new row.
- Keep repeating until all widgets are placed.

###### Bind that procedure to the resizing of the frame event.

###### I used 3 functions to make this work:

1. The function that runs the procedure.
2. The function that binds the resizing of the frame to the function.
3. The function that unbinds the resizing of the frame.

#### Here are the functions:

```
from tkinter import *


def _reorganizeWidgetsWithPlace(frame):
    widgetsFrame = frame
    widgetDictionary = widgetsFrame.children
    widgetKeys = []  # keys in key value pairs of the childwidgets

    for key in widgetDictionary:
        widgetKeys.append(key)

    # initialization/priming loop
    width = 0
    i = 0
    x = 0
    y = 0
    height = 0
    maxheight = 0
    # loop/algorithm for sorting
    while i < len(widgetDictionary):
        height = widgetDictionary[widgetKeys[i]].winfo_height()
        if height > maxheight:
            maxheight = height

        width = width + widgetDictionary[widgetKeys[i]].winfo_width()

        # always place first widget at 0,0
        if i == 0:
            x = 0
            y = 0
            width = widgetDictionary[widgetKeys[i]].winfo_width()

        # if after adding width, this exceeds the frame width, bump
        # widget down.  Use maximimum height so far to bump down
        # set x at 0 and start over with new row, reset maxheight
        elif width > widgetsFrame.winfo_width():
            y = y + maxheight
            x = 0
            width = widgetDictionary[widgetKeys[i]].winfo_width()
            maxheight = height

        # if after adding width, the widget row length does not exceed
        # frame with, add the widget at the start of last widget's
        # x value

        else:
            x = width-widgetDictionary[widgetKeys[i]].winfo_width()

        # place the widget at the determined x value
        widgetDictionary[widgetKeys[i]].place(x=x, y=y)
        i += 1
    widgetsFrame.update()


def organizeWidgetsWithPlace(frame):
    _reorganizeWidgetsWithPlace(frame)
    frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: _reorganizeWidgetsWithPlace(frame))
    _reorganizeWidgetsWithPlace(frame)


def stopOrganizingWidgetsWithPlace(frame):
    frame.unbind("<Configure>")
```

#### And here is an example of them in use:

```
def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x250")
    myframe = Frame(root)
    # make sure frame expands to fill parent window
    myframe.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

    buttonOrganize = Button(myframe, text='start organizing',
                            command=lambda: organizeWidgetsWithPlace(myframe))
    buttonOrganize.pack()

    buttonStopOrganize = Button(myframe, text='stop organizing',
                                command=lambda: stopOrganizingWidgetsWithPlace(myframe))
    buttonStopOrganize.pack()

    ##### a bunch of widgets #####
    button = Button(myframe, text="---a random Button---")
    canvas = Canvas(myframe, width=80, height=20, bg="orange")
    checkbutton = Checkbutton(myframe, text="---checkbutton----")
    entry = Entry(myframe, text="entry")
    label = Label(myframe, text="Label", height=4, width=20)
    listbox = Listbox(myframe, height=3, width=20)
    message = Message(myframe, text="hello from Message")
    radioButton = Radiobutton(myframe, text="radio button")
    scale_widget = Scale(myframe, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(myframe)
    textbox = Text(myframe, width=3, height=2)
    textbox.insert(END, "Text Widget")
    spinbox = Spinbox(myframe, from_=0, to=10)

    root.mainloop()

main()
```

###### Notice:

That you do not need to grid, pack or place them.  As long as you specify the frame, that will all be done at once when the function is called.  So that is very convenient.  And it can be annoying if you grid a widget, then try to pack another, then try to place another and you get that error that you can only use one geometry manager.  I believe this will simply overwrite the previous choices and place them.  I believe you can just drop this function in and it will take over management.  So far that has always worked for me, but I think you should really not try to mix and match geometry managers.

Notice that initially the buttons are packed, but after pressing the button, they are placed.

I have added the "WithPlace" naming to the functions because I have a similar set of functions that do something very similar with the grid manager.

Comment: FYI I have 2 packages that address the question - a "FlowFrame" object which inherits from the Frame class with an addWidget() method and "tkinterflow" which adds .flow() to pack, place, & grid.   They're at https://pypi.org/project/flowframe and https://pypi.org/project/tkinterflow with a readme and examples.  I add this comment because they asked  "is there something like Swing's FlowLayout for TkInter?" Ans - yes, those 2 packages.  But I want to share some basic ideas about how this can be achieved because I think stack overflow is about sharing problem solving and ideas not just packages.